# Difference between TortoiseGit Git Sync and Pull?

Tags: git, synchronization, tortoisegit, git-pull

I am comming from a SVN environment and I am exploring Git with TortoiseGit.

When I right-click a 'checked-out' Git repository, I can perform a `Git Sync` command, but also a `Pull` command.

What is the difference between those two functions precisely?

Comment: See documentation https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-sync.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TortoiseGit Sync Dialog can perform multiple synchronization operations in one dialog, including

- pull (or fetch or ...)
- push
- submodule update

"Sync" is not a Git concept, it is unique to TortoiseGit only!

TortoiseGit Pull Dialog only performs pull operations, but it has more advanced options for the users to choose.

Comment: I think sync is now part of git: -- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Tortoise's "git sync..." dialog includes much more than just a submodule sync, which is what git's "sync" command is for. The dialog is a central control panel for selecting multiple operations all in one place.

Answer (score 9):

I haven't TortoiseGit, but, from mind: Pull is unidirectional data-transfer (from remote to local), Sync (as it written) is bidirectional (pull+push) and publish local changes into remote